# Selection sort a roster

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

So I'm supposed to create a program that asks for the class size. Then using that size, you enter a students name and score until you fill the class size. After doing that, I'm supposed to invoke a selectionSort method to sort the scores in descending order. So the output is essentially a table. One column is name, the other is score and the scores are supposed to be in descending order with their appropriate name. I have most of the program down, I just can't figure out how to tie the students name to their score that was entered. Can someone steer me in the right direct? I'm at a loss. Here is my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Roster {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        System.out.print("Enter the size of the class: ");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        double[]score = new double[size];
        String[]name = new String[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            System.out.print("Please enter a student name: ");
            String n = input.next();
            name[i] = n;
            System.out.print("Please enter " + n + "'s score: ");
            double s = input.nextDouble();
            score[i] = s;
            System.out.println();
        }
        selectionSort(score,name);
        System.out.print("THe class size is: " + size + "\n");
        System.out.print("Name         Score\n");
        System.out.print("----         -----\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
            System.out.println(name[i] + " " + score[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void selectionSort(double[] score, String[] name){
        for(int i = score.length-1; i > 0; i--){
                int maxIndex = 0;
                for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                    if(score[j] < score[maxIndex])
                        maxIndex = j;
                double temp = score[i];
                score[i] = score[maxIndex];
                score[maxIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing you could do is when you swap scores, you can swap names with the same index.

Comment: @mstbaum how would I go about swap the names with the same index?

Comment: You have index `i` and index `maxIndex` so use those to index your `name` array and do the same swap that you're doing with the `score` array (you would also need a temp String).  I would really recommend using a class though, like I described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I already commented a simple solution, but really the best thing to do would be to create a class of roster entries:

```
public class RosterEntry {
    private String name;
    private double score;

    /*Accessors and Mutators*/
}
```

Then in your `main` you can maintain a list or array of `RosterEntry`s so that when you make swaps in the selection sort, you swap `RosterEntry`s instead of scores and names individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class of pairs, which you store in an array. As such:

```
public class MyPair
{
    private final String name;
    private final Double score;

    public MyPair(String aName, Double aScore)
    {
        name= aName;
        score = aScore;
    }

    public String getName()   { return name; }
    public Double getScore() { return score; }
}
```

You can then create a simple array of type MyPair,

```
MyPair[] pupils = new MyPair(20);
```

You can access details of pupils by

```
pupils[i].getName;
```

or

```
pupils[i].getScore;
```